# There was an error during dll loading : D:\\xulRunner\\freebl3.dll, error - 18

Tags: c#

LoadLibraryEx method throws me an exception of There was an error during dll loading : D:\xulRunner\freebl3.dll, error - 18. But files exists...

Anyone knows what that means?

CODE:

```
string XulRunnerPath = @"D:\xulRunner";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(XulRunnerPath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                LoadWin32Library(file);
            }


[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllFilePath, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public extern static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr dllPointer);

        static uint LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002;
        static uint LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040;
        static uint LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008;

        public static IntPtr LoadWin32Library(string dllFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IntPtr moduleHandle = LoadLibraryEx(dllFilePath, IntPtr.Zero, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
                if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // I'm gettin last dll error
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        string.Format("There was an error during dll loading : {0}, error - {1}", dllFilePath, errorCode)
                        );
                }

                return moduleHandle;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't load library {0}{1}{2}", dllFilePath, Environment.NewLine, exc.Message), exc);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading a native library/DLL, or a .NET library/DLL? If you're doing native work, I would highly recommend adding a tag to that effect.

This article might help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dyninvok.aspx. While it is a little old, things haven't changed too much on this front. I would think you could make the solution better via the use of dynamic, but it is not something that I have tried.

Good luck,
Erick